# How to override inherited_resources with the rails scaffold command

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activescaffold, inherited-resources

I am using the active_admin gem in my Rails 3 application, which has as a dependency inherited_resources.  I am somewhat of a newb and would rather avoid the black box qualities of inherited_resources for my own controllers, however, when I run the default rails g scaffold command, the controllers that are generated are inheriting from inherited_resources. I know that I can manually override this by inheriting from ApplicationController, however, I would like to be able to generate the default rails scaffolds if possible.

Comment: found it. found a reference to the -c command line argument for 'rails generate scaffold'. To force rails to use the normal scaffold generator, add -c=scaffold_generator to the end of the command

Answer (score 12, accepted):

-c=scaffold_controller

or add this to config/application.rb

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.scaffold_controller "scaffold_controller"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Also noted in an issue thread over at github: https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources/issues/195